# Transaction rollback in innodb mysql/php with mysql_query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

I am trying to execute a bunch of statements inserting into multiple tables within a transaction, but when I call for a rollback, everything returns without error but the data is inserted!

```
//Returns "YES"
$supports = mysql_query( "SELECT SUPPORT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ENGINES WHERE ENGINE = 'InnoDB'" );

//Start transaction
mysql_query( "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0" );
mysql_query( "START TRANSACTION" );

//Do some inserts
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO ...." );
$lastId = mysql_query( "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastId" );
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO...." );

//Try to rollback
mysql_query( "ROLLBACK" );
mysql_query( "SET AUTOCOMMIT=1" );
```

The tables are all created as InnoDB tables. Running `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` shows all tables are created as:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    ...the columns...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the only commands within the transaction `INSERT` commands?

Comment: @eggyal One other command: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastId`

Comment: Are you able to use an interactive client to narrow down whether the problem lies with your command sequence or PHP?

Comment: @eggyal if you mean mysql from command line, yes. I will try executing those exact statements. Do you see anything wrong with them? Any special connection flags I should be setting?

Comment: No, nothing there appears to be wrong.  If I had to guess right now, I'd be leaning towards investigating whether the calls to `mysql_query()` are taking place in the same database session, but let's eliminate one thing at time...

Comment: @eggyal It appears rollback is working within the mysql command line interface. I set autocommit, started the transaction, inserted, read the insert id, inserted into the second table, called a rollback and neither table has the data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51770/discussion-between-eggyal-and-don-rhummy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@eggyal led to the answer. My `START TRANSACTION` was inside a loop instead of outside it, so it was starting multiple transactions and only rolling back the last one.